# Spring JPA (Hibernate) No qualifying bean of type: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm using Spring-boot, so a war deployed in Tomcat 7.  When I start the app I get  the following:

```
  Dec 30, 2013 7:41:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2013-12-30 19:41:06 INFO  DispatcherServlet:461 - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
  2013-12-30 19:41:06 INFO  SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:315 - Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
  2013-12-30 19:41:06 INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:181 - Mapped "{[/user],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public com.cloudfordev.controlpanel.orm.User com.cloudfordev.controlpanel.GetController.getUser(int)
  2013-12-30 19:41:07 INFO  SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:315 - Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
  2013-12-30 19:41:07 INFO  SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:315 - Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
  2013-12-30 19:41:08 INFO  DispatcherServlet:480 - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 1957 ms
  Dec 30, 2013 7:41:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Dec 30, 2013 7:41:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Dec 30, 2013 7:41:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Dec 30, 2013 7:41:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Dec 30, 2013 7:41:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Tomcat
Dec 30, 2013 7:41:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Dec 30, 2013 7:41:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2013-12-30 19:41:08 INFO  AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer$AutoConfigurationReportLogger:108 -


=========================
AUTO-CONFIGURATION REPORT
=========================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   MessageSourceAutoConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.MessageSource; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration#propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer; SearchStrategy: current) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate,org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate,org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager (OnClassCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration.JpaWebConfiguration
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - SpEL expression on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration: #{true} (OnExpressionCondition)

   DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet (OnClassCondition)
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory; SearchStrategy: all) found the following [tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory] (OnBeanCondition)

   DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration#dispatcherServlet
      - no DispatcherServlet found (DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DefaultDispatcherServletCondition)

   EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedTomcat
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory; SearchStrategy: current) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration#serverProperties
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.properties.ServerProperties; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet,org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annota
tion.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter (OnClassCondition)
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet,org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annota
tion.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration#hiddenHttpMethodFilter
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#defaultViewResolver
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)


Negative matches:
-----------------

   RabbitAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate,com.rabbitmq.client.Channel (OnClassCondition)

   AopAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect,org.aspectj.lang.reflect.Advice (OnClassCondition)

   BatchAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher (OnClassCondition)

   JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository (OnClassCondition)

   MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: com.mongodb.Mongo,org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.DbcpConfiguration
      - org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource DataSource class not found (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.BasicDatabaseCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedConfiguration
      - no embedded database detected (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedDatabaseCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.JdbcTemplateConfiguration
      - no existing bean configured database (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.DatabaseCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.TomcatConfiguration
      - org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource DataSource class not found (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.TomcatDatabaseCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration#transactionManager
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JmsTemplateAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate,javax.jms.ConnectionFactory (OnClassCondition)

   DeviceResolverAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor,org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver (OnClassCondition)

   HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement,javax.persistence.EntityManager,org.hibernate.ejb.HibernateEntityManager (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement,javax.persistence.EntityManager,org.hibernate.ejb.HibernateEntityManager (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ReactorAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: reactor.spring.context.config.EnableReactor (OnClassCondition)

   ThymeleafAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine (OnClassCondition)

   EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedJetty
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server,org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader (OnClassCondition)

   MultipartAutoConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#beanNameViewResolver
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.View; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#viewResolver
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.View; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebSocketAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler (OnClassCondition)



  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:356)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1180)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:660)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:552)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:293)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:749)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:738)
        at com.cloudfordev.controlpanel.Application.main(Application.java:14)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:559)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:515)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:682)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:655)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:353)

        ... 22 more
```

This is how my Application boots:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

When my Spring controller handles the connection:

```
@Controller
public class GetController {

    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired 
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody User getUser(@RequestParam(value="id", required=true) int id) {
        User user = null;

        user = userService.getUser(id);

        return user;
    }
}
```

It does a getUser on the userService:

```
@Component
public class UserService {

    private UserDAO UserDao;

    public UserDAO getUserDao() {
        return UserDao;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setUserDao(UserDAO UserDao) {
        this.UserDao = UserDao;
    }

    public User getUser(int id) {
        return getUserDao().load(id);
    }
}
```

Which uses the userDao to find the entity:

```
@Repository("userDao")
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class UserDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void insert(User user) {
        entityManager.persist(user);
    }

    public User load(int id) {
        return entityManager.find(User.class, id);
    }
}
```

I have the following spring-config.xml in /src/main/resources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mydomain.orm" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="userPersistenceUnit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="HSQL" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb" />
        <property name="username" value="my_user" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And last but not least the following /src/main/resources/persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="userPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" >
    <class>com.mydomain.orm.User</class>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

What do I need to do to resolve this error?

Comment: Why are you creating the context inside the controller and then destroy it again in the method?

Comment: I honestly don't know :(  I'm new to contexts, beans, jpa, and hibernate.  I guess the context should be created automatically by the servlet transaction... I closed it because Eclipse was upset about a resource leak.

Comment: You should never create a context this way, just inject your UserService in your controller via `@Autowired UserService`.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings I updated the GetController.  You mean like that?  That seems much better.

Comment: I added the improved code to my answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're wanting an `EntityManager` injected, but you don't have any injection annotations on the field, and "factory" is the wrong qualifier in any case. Annotate your field with `@PersistenceContext`, using `unitName` if needed to distinguish between multiple persistence units.

**Answer to edited question:** Your XML file isn't getting included, because you start from the `Application` class, and Spring just follows the `@ComponentScan` from there. Add this import to your `Application` class (or any scanned `@Configuration` class):

```
@ImportResource("classpath:spring-config.xml")
```

Alternately, you can migrate your XML configuration to the JavaConfig format, which Spring will component-scan.

Comment: Your XML file isn't getting loaded. I'm looking up how to do this from JavaConfig. Alternately, you can migrate everything to Java.

Comment: Bingo that did it!  Oh thank you, Chrylis, I shouted for joy when it worked.  I had been wondering if it was not loading the spring-config.xml, but I always thought that meant a classpath problem.  YAY IT WORKS!

Comment: I will award the bounty when the timer expires.  Say, do you see any other improvements that should be made here?

Comment: Other than using JavaConfig and maybe a Spring Repository instead of a custom DAO if appropriate, not really. And don't feel a need to post a bounty, especially a big one!

Comment: Oh the two of you definitely earned it.  I've learned so much in the last few hours and ... ITS WORKING :)  I wish I could award to both of you

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that your are using annotation configuration which already searches the classpath for annotated beans this tries to instantiate the `UserDAO` but your don't provide a EntityManagerFactory here.

You can combine the JavaConfig with the XML configuration via `@ImportResource("classpath:spring-config.xml")`.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ImportResource("classpath:spring-config.xml")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
@Controller
public class GetController {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody User getUser(@RequestParam(value="id", required=true) int id) {

        return userService.getUser(id);
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO UserDao;

    public User getUser(int id) {
        return getUserDao().load(id);
    }
}
```

Might I suggest using [SpringData](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) for the DAO you'll save much boilerplate code.

Comment: Oh that is much nicer.  I think Autowired finally clicked for me.  I would like to save boilderplate code, but I'm wary to spend another several days learning when progress is needed.  But I will look into it for sure, starting right now.

Comment: @LynnOwens If you're just now starting with `@Autowired`, I really recommend using `@Inject` instead whenever possible. Always best to go with the (new) standard.

Comment: I have now gotten SpringData working... Going to investigate @Inject now

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the autoconfig report that came out of the crash I can see that there is no `DataSource` defined. Spring Boot will create one for you if you have the right stuff on your classpath - eg at a minimum to get something working include h2 or hsqldb on your classpath.

Incidentally, the XML file is redundant if you use Spring Boot the right way.

Comment: Thanks, realized I didn't have a JDBC driver for autoconfigure to build from in my dependencies after reading this.